# Reactjs: Reusable button component to generate a component provided as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to create a reusable component - a button `<AddButton />` - that when clicked will generate another component. In order to make it reusable the idea is that the component to be generated will be provided as a prop to `AddButton`.

I am exploring the use of render props to achieve this, though I've become a bit confused about how to go about it. Would I still need to control state in the parent component in order to achieve what I am looking to do? If so, how would I account for any existing components that are not dynamically added using the button? Or, as a newcomer to react, am I misunderstanding how modular/reusable components can be, and do I need to adjust my thinking?

Example code below, where `AddButton` is the reusable add component, and `<Skills />` (in this example), is the component I am looking to generate dynamically, in addition to the 4 example skills that are provided.

```
    class TitleContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { };
  }

  handleClick = (e) => {};

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Skills name='JavaScript' />
        <Skills name='TypeScript' />
        <Skills name='Bongo Drums' />
        <Skills name='Fishing' />
        <AddButton render={(name) => <Skills name='Edit me' />} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

n.b. I would like to use the `AddButton` component elsewhere on my site to generate other components so would like it to be as reusable as possible. I would also like to achieve this with just the plain react framework and without any additional libraries. Thanks

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the goal is here. You want the last `Skills` component to handle click events on the DOM node it renders? What should `AddButton` do except of handling click events? If that is the only thing it does you will not need it at all.

Comment: @trixn the `Skills` component has its own functionality. I am looking to use `AddButton` to add more `Skills` to the DOM. But I want `AddButton` to be reusable elsewhere on my site to generate other components.

Comment: Yes, but what should `AddButton` do internally that justifies its existence in the first place? For example, where does the argument `name` in your render prop function come from? You did not provide anything to `AddButton` except of the render prop itself. So what logic is `AddButton` supposed to encapsulate? Can you add an example of that?

Comment: @trixn I think that's the part I am stuck with. I'm not sure. I'm wondering whether I can have some logic in there which will render whatever Component is given to it as a prop. Or whether this is not the way to go, and the container component (in my code above, `TitleContainer` should just have its own `<button></button>` with logic to render more `Skills` components. Hence my asking here!

Comment: Well, if `AddButton` does something internally that is always the same it might make sense to have it. But unless we know what it should do we can't tell if that is the right approach. Should it perform an API request? Should it add certain data to a state that is external to it? You haven't provided any information about what it should do except of rendering something else. You wouldn't need it if the only thing it does is rendering something you provide from outside without any modification. You could just render the `Skills` directly in that case.

Comment: What we need is an example of the logic that always repeats and that you are trying to abstract into `AddButton`. If `AddButton` only renders what's provided through `render` you don't need it at all. It would just be an additional layer that does nothing.

Comment: Thank you. The purpose is literally just to generate another component when clicked. There is no additional functionality or API calling etc. required. So I guess I should just handle that logic inside the parent component using `state` and relevant methods?

Comment: So the question is then, what do you mean with "generate another component"? In react, you do not "generate components" you generate/alter state and react will render the components accordingly.

Comment: @trixn that is what I mean, I will add some logic to the parent component that updates the state in order to render additional components.

Comment: In that case it would be sufficient to add an `onClick` prop to the `Skills` component which will be passed down to the underlying built-in element and handle that click in the component that manages the state of `skills`. You don't need an extra component to forward a click handler if that component doesn't know how to handle the click.

Comment: If I am looking to render more `Skills` components within the `TitleContainer` (see example code above) then surely I would handle all of that within `TitleContainer` and not need to pass any props to the existing `Skills` components?

Comment: I find `TitleContainer` already to be a confusing name, as it doesn't seem to do what its name suggests. If it renders skills shouldn't it be called `Skills` or `SkillsList` or `SkillsGrid` and each individual skill component `Skill` rather than `Skills` with `s`? It seems like you are asking how to render a dynamic list of items and provide some generic add functionality. It that what you want?

Comment: yes you are right. This was just an example in this case. I am looking to render a dynamic list of items and provide some add functionality though. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add an optional `onClick` handler to an individual skill component and handle that to add a skill.

Example using [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) instead of class components:

```
const SKILLS = [{name: 'JavaScript'}, {name: 'TypeScript'}, {name: 'Bongo Drums'}, {name: 'Fishing'}];

const Skill = ({name, onClick}) => (
  <div onClick={onClick} style={{border: onClick ? '1px solid black' : 'none'}}>
    <p>{name}</p>
  </div>
);

const Skills = () => {
  const [skills, setSkills] = useState(SKILLS);

  const handleAdd = () => setSkills(current => [...current, {name: 'New Skill'}]);

  return (
    <div>
      {skills.map(skill => (
        <Skill name={skill.name} />
      ))}
      <Skill name="add a skill" onClick={handleAdd} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit compassionate-cdn-7xtvl]

Now if you wanted to abstract the adding logic away you could use a custom hook:

```
const useList = initial => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState(initial);
    const append = item => setItems(current => [...current, item]);
    // other handlers for operations like remove, move, shuffle etc. also possible        

    return {items, append};
};
```

Usage:

```
const Skills = () => {
  const {items, append} = useList(SKILLS);

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(skill => <Skill name={skill.name} />)}
      <Skill name="add a skill" onClick={() => append({name: 'New Skill'})} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I will see how I get on with this. I am learning how to use class components first before moving onto functional components, so will rewrite what you've provided.

Comment: @LearningPython If you are currently learning react I strongly suggest learning hooks first. The react docs are currently in the process of being re-written to be entirely hooks first. Class components are considered "legacy" for backwards compatibility but the recommended way to write components is with hooks as they are way more composable and less "boilerplaty". The docs currently lack quality examples but there are good third party tutorials already.